# Error while uploading image on Heroku Node.js app

Tags: node.js, heroku, formidable

Route-

```
app.post('/add-product',(req,res)=>{
var image=randomstring.generate({
    length: 12
});
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    var oldpath = files.pimage.path;
    var newpath = __dirname;
    var path=newpath.split('controllers');
    path=path[0]+'/public/productimages/'+image+".jpg";
    fs.readFile(oldpath, function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // Write the file
       fs.writeFile(path, data, function (err) {
           if (err) throw err;
       });
    });
   });
});
```

Got some problem with uploading images to Heroku server, on Localhost everything work great. But on Heroku when I upload image, my app is getting crashed on these lines.

```
fs.writeFile(path, data, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Heroku log screenshot:

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/tX0Ta.png]

After changing '/public.....' to 'public/productimages/....'

I am getting :
no such file or directory, open '/app/public/productimages/8sRueNlG2k3F.jpg'

Comment: Did you run heroku logs --tail to see what the log says?

Comment: 00:00 app[web.1]: /app/controllers/user.js:247
00:00 app[web.1]: if (err) throw err;
00:00 app[web.1]: ^
00:00 app[web.1]:
00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app//public/productimages/F8MboSYV62SZ.jpg'
00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! maalikk@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!

Comment: Please attach a log screenshot.

Comment: @RohanDhar Please check it I've attached the log screenshot

Comment: @RohanDhar https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX0Ta.png

Comment: I don't find a screenshot. Could you please attach the screenshot again?

Comment: Ok, I got the screenshot. There seems to be a problem with your path. Remove '/public' and try just 'public/productimages/' and check

Comment: @RohanDhar tried but not working

Comment: Please send the log screenshot with the updated route

Comment: @RohanDhar https://i.imgur.com/y5sKgZX.png

Comment: @RohanDhar Please Check the screenshot . It will be a great help . Thanks

Comment: The directory to which you're trying to save probably doesn't exist. Make sure it does, because it won't be automagically created when you try to write a file to it.

Comment: @robertklep It worked Thanks .It means that empty folders are not being uploaded to git as well as Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors are typically caused by the target directory (in your case, `/app/public/productimages/`) not yet existing.

You can use a package like [`mkdirp`](https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp) to create the directory when your app starts, or you could create the directory locally and create an empty placeholder file (named `.placeholder`, for instance) that you commit to your Git repository (because Git only deals with files, not directories, you can't add a completely empty directory to a repository).